# VS2008 linker error PRJ0002 when a build folder is open in Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm building my C++/MFC project in Visual Studio 2008 in Release configuration. To run the tests I later drag all built executables into a virtual machine. To do that I keep the `Release` folder open in Windows Explorer with executables (being built) selected.

Unfortunately, at random times, when I attempt to build my project I get the following linker error in VS:

> Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe'.

Is there any way to fix this error?

PS. My current resolution is to close the `Release` folder in Windows Explorer and re-build solution, but it is very inconvenient because I then have to open that folder again and select all necessary files in it.

PS2. My OS is Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround i used in the past is to have a batch file in the vm that copies the file from the shared folder to a vm-only folder and execute the files from there.

It's fairly simple really, create a file 'test.bat' in your vm:

```
copy Z:\w2k3\%1 c:\test\
c:\test\%1
```

Then call it like:
test.bat test_target.exe

z:\w2k3 is the mounted vmware folder, c:\test is a local folder in the vm.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your batch file? I'm using VMware Workstation as my VM.

Comment: @c00000fd added an example.

Comment: Oh, you're using a shared folder for that. Hmm. OK. But then, how do I place those files from the mounted folder in the VM to the needed location?